# Drupals Date-Module and translation

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using a drupal 7 as my CMS, and I really do love it. But there is one little thing I can't find out. It has to do with the Date-Module. It's working fine, but I can't find a way to translate it. There are some keywords like "to" or "All day" and I need to translate that in german.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the "to" is translateable - I found out, that I had to translate the following string: `!start-date to !end-date`. But the "All day" phrase doesn't work, and it also uses the t() function. Only when I remove the other parameters, it works

Answer (score 0):

Date related text are translatable. (See [this](http://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/si/translate?sid=708564) for an example)
The best way is contributing to localize.drupal.org with correct text strings.  date-related strings are under "datatime" and "date settings" contexts.

Also you can make a custom .po file and add these strings and their translated strings to it. Not linking to softwares - there are many popular ones that come up on oogle searches.

also, make sure that the text field is in t() function.

Comment: thanks :)
well... the "to" is translateable - I found out, that I had to translate the following string:
    !start-date to !end-date
But the "All day" phrase doesn't work, and it also uses the t() function. Only when I remove the other parameters, it works.